# katalon test case failure:Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, katalon-studio

Running katalon test cases on Linux server through Jenkins and getting below error:

> `/home/qateam/Documents/Katalon_Studio_Linux_64-6.2.2_jenkins/./katalon -noSplash -data=/var/www/html/qateam/samidha/katalon_data -runMode=console -consoleLog -noExit -projectPath="/var/www/html/qateam/samidha/project/qa/testproject/project.prj" -retry=0 -testSuitePath=“Test Suites/Sort_Filter_ProductCount_Loadmore_Emi” -executionProfile=“default” -browserType=“Chrome (headless)”`
>
> `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /var/www/html/qateam/samidha/project/qa/testproject`

**Note:** When running through Jenkins it is just navigating to the Project Folder and not navigating to the Driver Folder.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to make this clear: this works when run directly from shell, but not from Jenkins?

Comment: No, i am getiing the same error from jenkins as well as from shell.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right directory? Where is katalon binary found?

Comment: yes.. i am running katalon command from project folder.

Comment: /home/qateam/Documents/Katalon_Studio_Linux_64-6.2.2_jenkins this the katalon binary path. jenkins user have all  the permission